# wacom-tools for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: package-management, wacom

I recently got a new Wacom Intuos tablet and I'm using it for playing Osu!

Now it worked just fine out of the box but I'd like to configure it more specifically with the wacom-tools Tool which iirc has support for linux. I found the package on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/wacom-tools) but it's a bit odd and I'm not able to install it.
I need the tool to map the tablet to a specific section of the screen so I'd really like to get it working.

Comment: Can you please answer this thread ? please please 
http://askubuntu.com/q/538335/339674

Comment: Is this article I wrote long ago of any help? [Remapping a graphic tablet in Linux (using xinput)](http://bartssolutions.blogspot.be/2013/05/wacom-intuos-1-setup-on-ubuntu.html). It explains how to remap the tablet-screen relation using xinput on the command line. (I know it's not exactly an answer to the question, but it might be a solution to the problem?).